# How to connect to a ssh tunneled database on host from container?

Tags: mysql, docker, ssh, ssh-tunnel

So I am currently running a docker container on a host machine that is connected to a remote MySQL database via SSH tunneling. I have configured the option `extra_hosts` in the container to `"host.docker.internal:host-gateway"`. This allows me to access the host machine using `host.docker.internal` from within the container. However, only http ports (`80` and `443`) are available and the `extra_hosts` options do not seem to bind the `3306` port as shown in the images below:

Host

[image]

Container

[image]

What steps should I take to enable access to the `3306` port?

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  web-server:
    image: nginx:1.21.1
    container_name: "nginx-server"
    build: 
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: ../.docker/nginx/dockerfile
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - .docker/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - backend
    networks:
      - network

  backend:
    container_name: "backend"
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: ../.docker/php/dockerfile
    environment:
      DB_HOST: host.docker.internal
      DB_PORT: 3306
      DB_DATABASE: db
      DB_USERNAME: db
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/var/www/html
    networks:
      cnetwork:
        ipv4_address: 10.5.0.5
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"

networks:
  cnetwork:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 10.5.0.0/16
```

.docker/php/dockerfile

```
FROM composer:1.9.2 AS composer
WORKDIR /composer

RUN mkdir bootstrap bootstrap/cache \
    storage storage/framework \
    storage/framework/sessions storage/framework/views storage/framework/cache
COPY composer.json composer.lock* /composer/
RUN composer install --no-scripts --ignore-platform-reqs

FROM php:8.0-fpm

WORKDIR /var/www/html
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends unzip libgmp-dev \
  && apt purge -y --auto-remove && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo_mysql gmp && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli

COPY . /var/www/html
COPY --from=composer /composer/ /tmp/composer/
COPY .env /tmp/.env

EXPOSE 8000

CMD cp -r /tmp/composer/. /var/www/html && \
    cp /tmp/.env /var/www/html && \
    php artisan key:generate && \
    php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

.docker/nginx/dockerfile

```
FROM node:14-alpine as build

ENV NODE_ENV=production
WORKDIR /app
COPY /package.json /package-lock.json* ./
RUN yarn install --production
COPY . .
RUN yarn build

FROM nginx:1.23.3 as production

ENV NODE_ENV=production
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html

CMD [ "nginx","-g","daemon off;" ]
```